# Rigorous definition of derivative of a real-valued function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, partial-derivative

I am learning Real Analysis through the book Analysis 2 of Terence Tao and there is a notation of Partial derivative (in Definition 6.3.7 below).

In the definition, the author uses the notation $\quad\frac{d}{dt} f(x_0 + t.e_j)|_{t=0} \quad$ without stating its definition in the previous chapters. (Please note that $e_j = (0,0,0,..1,0,0)$ ($i.e.$ the row vector with all zeros except for the $j^{th}$ element).

I understand the meaning of that notation is to take the $derivative$ of each element of the vector $f(x_0 + t.e_j)$ with respect to $t$.
But I am wondering whether there is a rigorous definition of derivative of a vector-valued function with respect to a single variable ?

[image]

Comment: That's already it. Although conceptually, you would prefer to think of the limiting process for the derivative as converging in some vector metric rather than componentwise (but in finite dimensions this distinction can be shown to be inconsequential).

Comment: @Ian: Thank you very much for your response. Is there any definition of that notation that revokes some kind of $epsilon$ $delta$ like the definition of normal derivative ? Or it it just a kind of $operation$ on a vector ? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering whether there is a rigorous definition of derivative of a vector-valued function with respect to a single variable ?

Check Definition 6.2.2 in the book. What you want is a special case of differentiability of function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ with $n=1$.

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please show me how to put an image (for example your image of Def 6.2.2) into a box like in your comment ?

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge: If you click on "Edit" under the answer, you will see how it is done. Basically, I use `>` as in `>[![enter image description here][1]][1]`